# Extract multiple numeric value from a data frame column and store in separate columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(Income = c("$100to$200","under$100","above$1000"))
```

I would like this as output

```
df_final <- data.frame(Avg = c(150,100,1000))
```

I would like to extract the numeric value from the income column, if there are two numbers, take the average, if there is only one number, take that number.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Income, ~ sapply(str_extract_all(.x, '\\d+'), \(x) {strsplit(x, ',') |>
      as.numeric() |> mean()})))

  Income
1    150
2    100
3   1000
```

Answer (score 2):

A few key steps here. First we need to clean our data, in this case getting rid of the `$` makes thing easier. Then we'll split into a From and To column. Finally we need to convert to numeric and calculate the row means.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Income = gsub("$", "", Income, fixed = TRUE)) %>% 
  separate(Income, "to|under|above", into = c("From", "To")) %>% 
  mutate_all(.,as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(Avg = rowMeans(.,na.rm =TRUE))

  From   To  Avg
1  100  200  150
2   NA  100  100
3   NA 1000 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  transmute(
    Avg = stringr::str_extract_all(Income, "(?<=\\$)\\d+") %>%
      lapply(as.numeric) %>% 
      sapply(mean)
  )
   Avg
1  150
2  100
3 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

A `stringr` approach using `gsub` to get the numerics, `str_squish` to remove the white space and `str_split` to get the entries in case of more then one value.

```
library(stringr)

data.frame(Avg = sapply(
  str_split(str_squish(gsub("[[:alpha:]$]", " ", df$Income)), " "), function(x) 
    sum(as.numeric(x)) / length(x)))
   Avg
1  150
2  100
3 1000
```